# QWebInspector Has No Tabs in Windows 7?

Tags: qt, windows-7, pyside

I would describe the QWebInspector as being blank were it not for the provided picture in this question:
[QWebInspector not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683780/qwebinspector-not-working-correctly)

Their picture is of a truly blank QWebInspector, whereas my QWebInspector looks like this:

[image: QWebInspector with Search Bar]

Notice that my QWebInspector has a gray bar with a search area at the top. Further, there's a bar at the bottom, with a console button in the lower left. I can click on the button or type in the search bar, but nothing happens when I do.

It seems to me the issue is that the tabs don't appear, and none of the content of the tabs appears.

I have two machines running Windows 7 - both show the same thing. I've tried various versions of (from 4.7.4 through 4.8.5) and none of them show anything else under Windows 7. Under OS X, it loads fine.

For what it's worth, I'm using PySide. I've tried versions 1.1.1 through 1.2.1, all of them show nothing.

Here's the relevant code:

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
webView = QtWebKit.QWebView()
app.setOrganizationName("Company")
app.setApplicationName("Product")

#I've tried just setting one or the other, but it never works.
QtWebKit.QWebSettings.globalSettings().setAttribute(QtWebKit.QWebSettings.WebAttribute.DeveloperExtrasEnabled, True)
webView.settings().setAttribute(QtWebKit.QWebSettings.WebAttribute.DeveloperExtrasEnabled, True)
webView.load(url) # A QUrl passed in from elsewhere.

window = QtGui.QMainWindow()
window.setCentralWidget(webView)
window.show()

inspect = QtWebKit.QWebInspector()
inspect.setPage(webView.page())
inspect.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing from PySide 1.1.1 to PySide 1.2.1 resolved this problem for me. You can get different versions of PySide for Windows here:

http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/pyside/